# HighCharts, HighChartTable - pie chart default slice

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need assistance on selecting a highcharts pie slice onLoad using HighCharts sister plugin HighChartTables.

Not using `<td class="data" data-graph-name="name" data-graph-item-highlight="1">XYZ</td>`

As this only pull out the slice, not the selected data behind it...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to achieve that in HighchartTable, but you can get this using chart.events.load callback, to find sliced point and just render report, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/36/

And code:

```
    highChartConfig.chart.events = {
        load: function () {
            var data = this.series[0].data,
                dLen = data.length,
                i = 0;

            while (dLen > i) {
                var point = data[i];
                if (point.sliced) {
                    $report.html('<h2>' + point.name + '</h2><p>' + point.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%</p>');
                    i = dLen;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work if you remove this:  <td data-graph-item-highlight="1">26.1</td>

Comment: however you've given me an idea about using: 'highChartConfig.chart.events = {
         load: function() {
              this.series[0].data[0].select();
        
          }
     }'

Comment: Something like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/47](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/47) but the slice() has disappeared?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to set: `highChartConfig.series[0].data[0].sliced = true;` ? See: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/49/

Comment: Actually one more question, how would I hide all open slices?

Comment: Set `visible: true/false` to show/hide slices on load. See: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/65/ About second comment, I don't know what do you mean..

Comment: You call `point.update({sliced: false});` or `point.slice(true/false);`.

Comment: Why your code should work..? Just call `point.slice()`, works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/69/

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/70](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/70/) select works better, however because on load it pulls out the first data[0], I want to be able to close that slice when you mouseOver over any other slices, it works fine if you mouseOver the slice that is opened. was just wondering if there is a selectAll(false), before I call this.select, hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: Simply store which slice was selected and deselect that point. See: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/72/

Comment: I have another issue [http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/76](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/76) Trying but failing to have an $each() to display that charts mouseOver/load events to the relevant chartOutput?

Comment: I think you need to store index of a chart so then use specific report element, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/77/

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to have a slice of the pie selected on initial load you use the `sliced` property. See this demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/). To do this you add a property to a point you want to have selected:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
        ['Firefox',   45.0],
        ['IE',       26.8],
        {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        },
        ['Safari',    8.5],
        ['Opera',     6.2],
        ['Others',   0.7]
    ]
}]
```

Comment: I'm not loading data via JSON Im using data from a table via their other plugin....

Comment: If possible can you put a representative jsFiddle.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/), you'll notice if you delete the x off the attr for Financials then the 'slice' pulls out but i require the label or 'data' to show as well, without having to code it in the div separately... hope this makes sense.

Comment: I've tried trigger(); the event.click but that doesnt seem to work either